# Is it possible to copy a dope sheet summary to another project?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, dopesheet

So I have 2 characters. I made a basic walking cycle animation for the first one and I want to do the same thing for the second character as well. Is it possible do this just by copying the dope sheet? [image]

My characters are not exactly the same but pretty similar.

Answer (score 1):

If you have saved your animations as Actions (Press the <kbd>F</kbd> button to save them), you can then import them into another project by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.  [image: Actions]